# spymemcached: checking connection before getting object

Tags: spymemcached

I'm not sure if what the best practice is for usign spymemcached but I see a lot of tutorials on the internet that does this:

```
  mc = new MemcachedClient(
            new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
                  .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY)
                    .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build(),
            AddrUtil.getAddresses("XXX"));

mc.set("1", 0, "Hello");
mc.get("1");
```

I was thinking that one should check if mc is actually connnected first before one does sets and gets stuff from mc?

I was thinking something like this in pseudocode:

```
    if (mc.getConnection().connectionsStatus().equals("I'm connected!")) {
//do the sets and gets inside the if statement
```

}

Although I don't know what to compare the connectionStatus with... I couldn't seem to find an example of this and whether this comparison is actually necessary?

In my scenario, I'm using spymemcached to store tokens and user ids. Each time a request is sent through to the server, the server retrieves it from mc first and if it is not there, it will retrieve it from my database. In effect, spymemcached is going to be hit hundreds of times a second and I don't know if checking the connectionsStatus is necessary each time an api call is made.

Answer (score 0):

As you use memcached in pure cache scenario, you may wish get fast fail if there is something wrong with the connection. **I suggest you needn't to check the connection status, but set a strict timeout limit for your operations**, such as:

```
        GetFuture<Object> future = mc.asyncGet("1");
        Object result = future.get(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

or set OpTimeout of ConnectionFactory:

```
  mc = new MemcachedClient(
            new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
                  .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY)
                    .setOpTimeout(10) // the unit is milliseconds
                    .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build(),
            AddrUtil.getAddresses("XXX"));
```

catch the exception after time elapsed and access your database.